# How can i remove duplicate tuples with scala? Cartesian Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

actually I have an RDD containing some protein names and their domains. I used the cartesian function to determine the possible pairs of it. As a result i obtained unfortunately duplicated pairs. How can i keep only one tuple and remove the duplicated one?
Here's an example:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|             Protein1               |                Protein2            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|(P0C2L1,IPR0179)                    |(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)        |
|(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)        |(P0C2L1,IPR0179)                    |
|(B2UDV1,IPR0104)                    |(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266)| 
|(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266)|(B2UDV1,IPR0104)                    |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I would like to have:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|             Protein1               |                Protein2            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|(P0C2L1,IPR0179)                    |(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)        |
|(B2UDV1,IPR0104)                    |(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266)| 
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please share a sample code snippet. It helps to build on that,

Comment: i didn't wrote any code i'm looking for it..

Comment: can you give an example of the pairs? The structure of the data is variable? What does the sample mean?

Comment: hey @amelie you should provide more explanation. for example prints of each rdd and how the cartesian rdd is getting duplicates prints etc. i am not able to reproduce your problem. also is this pair rdd or normal.

Comment: i hope this is more clear now @thebluephantom no it's not variable

Comment: @Manish yes these are rdd pairs but i wrote it in a table format so that you can understand me, I would be grateful if you helped me..

Comment: How many columns  will have the tuple? Two,  three,  four?

Comment: two columns as the first table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have assumed input data based on information provided and implemented below solution.

It does :

1. Converts RDD to spark dataframe.
2. Swaps every second input based on length(Protein1) > length(Protein2).
3. And uses the dropDuplicates method to remove duplicates.
4. Stores in dataframe and then in RDD.

Note: For this to work "length(Protein1) > length(Protein2)" has to meet. If more input data clarity is provided by OP, will work on more solutions.

```
//Creating the paired RDD as provided by OP
var x: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((("P0C2L1,IPR0179"), ("P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890")), (("P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890"),("P0C2L1,IPR0179") ), (("B2UDV1,IPR0104"),("Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266")), (("Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266"),("B2UDV1,IPR0104"))   ))

//Creating as spark dataframe out of this RDD
var combDF = spark.createDataFrame(x).toDF("Protein1","Protein2")
combDF.show(20,false)

//+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
//|Protein1                            |Protein2                            |
//+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
//|(P0C2L1,IPR0179)                    |(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)        |
//|(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)        |(P0C2L1,IPR0179)                    |
//|(B2UDV1,IPR0104)                    |(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266)|
//|(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266)|(B2UDV1,IPR0104)                    |
//+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+

// creating temporary views
combDF.createOrReplaceTempView("combDF")

// Below statement is only required for this example just to cast to struct
combDF = spark.sql("""select named_struct("col1", element_at(split(Protein1,","),1), "col2",  element_at(split(Protein1,","),2)) as Protein1,
                       named_struct("col1", element_at(split(Protein2,","),1), "col2",  element_at(split(Protein2,","),2)) as Protein2
                 from combDF""")
//end 

combDF.createOrReplaceTempView("combDF")
combDF.show()
var result = spark.sql("""
  |select case when length(Protein1_m) > length(Protein2_m) then element_at(protein_array, 2) 
  |            else element_at(protein_array, 1) 
  |            end as Protein1,
  |       case when length(Protein1_m) > length(Protein2_m) then element_at(protein_array, 1) 
  |            else element_at(protein_array, 2) 
  |            end as Protein2
  |from 
  |(select Protein1, Protein2, cast(Protein1 as string) as Protein1_m, cast(Protein2 as string) as Protein2_m,
  |        array(Protein1,Protein2) as protein_array
  |from combDF) a
""".stripMargin).dropDuplicates()
// Result in spark dataframe
result.show(20,false)

//+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
//|Protein1         |Protein2                             |
//+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
//|(B2UDV1,IPR0104) |(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266) |
//|(P0C2L1,IPR0179) |(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)         |
//+-------------------+-----------------------------------+

// result in RDD
var resultRDD = result.rdd
resultRDD.collect().foreach(println)

//[(B2UDV1,IPR0104),(Q4R8P0,IPR029058;IPR000073;IPR0266)]   
//[(P0C2L1,IPR0179),(P0CW05,IPR004372;IPR000890)]
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't work for me, here's the error :
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: combsDF; line 8 pos 80
combDF is my dataframe (cartesianDF as you wrote it)

Comment: Replace this line :
cartesianDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cartesionDF")
with cartesianDF.createOrReplaceTempView("combDF")

Comment: i have updated the answer as per your requirement @amelie . Also source table in spark.sql() statement needs to be modified to combDF as well

Comment: Another errors: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'length(a.`Protein1`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or binary) type, however, 'a.`Protein1`' is of struct<_1:string,_2:string> type.; line 2 pos 17;
'Project [CASE WHEN (length(Protein1#29) > length(Protein2#30)) THEN element_at(protein_array#33, 2) ELSE element_at(protein_array#33, 1) END AS Protein1#34, CASE WHEN (length(Protein1#29) > length(Protein2#30)) THEN element_at(protein_array#33, 1) ELSE element_at(protein_array#33, 2) END AS Protein2#35]

Comment: Hi @amelie ,can you share the combDF.printSchema()  output and also data types of columns of RDD used. As I assumed the input data to give this solution.

Comment: I have updated the spark sql query , please check if it works now

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to transform that rdd to a dataframe and using functions to remove duplicates.

Duplicate rows could be remove or drop from Spark DataFrame using `distinct()` and `dropDuplicates()` functions, `distinct()` can be used to remove rows that have the same values on all columns whereas `dropDuplicates()` can be used to remove rows that have the same values on multiple selected columns.

Comment: Not really an answer. The data is poorly understood and explained.